# Remove GitLab Build Dependency

Tags: gitlab

I have created a GitLab automated CI/CD build process that looks something like this:

[image: CI/CD Build]

And the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like this (removed actual commands since they're not important to this question):

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-windows:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - ...
  script:
    - ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ...
    expire_in: 3 month
  tags:
    - windows

build-linux-ubuntu:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - ...
  script:
    - ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ...
    expire_in: 3 month
  tags:
    - linux
    - ubuntu

test-windows:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - ...
  script:
    - ...
  after_script:
    - ...
  tags:
   - windows

test-linux-ubuntu:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - ...
  after_script:
    - ...
  tags:
    - linux
    - ubuntu

deploy-windows:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - ...
  script:
    - ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ...
  after_script:
  tags:
    - windows

deploy-linux-ubuntu:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - ...
  script:
    - ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ...
    expire_in: 3 month
  after_script:
    - ...
  tags:
    - linux
    - ubuntu
```

Now this has the downside of Linux taking longer to build/test/deploy than Windows, so the Windows job finishes much quicker and just sits waiting for the Linux job to complete. Then once both have completed, it moves on to the next step. However, the Windows and Linux jobs are completely independent of one another.

How can I get GitLab to build both Windows and Linux in parallel, without the cross-dependency? Something like this:

[image: CI/CD with dependency removed]

Comment: I think [DAGs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/directed_acyclic_graph/) are supposed to solve exactly this problem

Comment: @gronostaj That looks like exactly what I'm looking for! Though unfortunately when I add the `needs` keyword in, GitLab doesn't seem to change anything. When I use the GitLab CI Lint, it also doesn't say anything about the added `needs` keyword. I'm thinking that our GitLab installation may not support DAGs unfortunately.